# How to repair `information_schema`.`TABLES`?

Tags: mysql, information-schema, repair

I'm trying to list the contents of `information_schema`.`TABLES` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`TABLES` LIMIT 10
```

but it gives me an error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Then I tought that `REPAIR TABLE TABLES` should fix it, but it gave me:

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    396
Current database: information_schema

ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

Anyone had that problem before or have an idea what could I do to fix this ?

Comment: Perhaps your `mysql.users` table is messed up a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two entries (after restarting the server) in the `error.log` like this:

```
InnoDB: Unable to find the AUTOINC column role_id in the InnoDB table database/table.
```

after dropping both tables everything was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your my.conf file and see if raising the following values fixes this issue for you.

```
interactive_timeout
wait_timeout
```

Comment: They are both set to `28800`, I don't think that will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try and fix your users table at MySQL using Grant. Usually when I had privileges access problems, this is how I solved them.
Also, please take a look at the following [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45959) -